# JavaScript Callback Errors or Doesn't Run

Tags: javascript, function, callback, keyup

I'm working with an array of cells (in qualtrics surveys) and have tried to write a function called watchSet that you can pass a set of cells and a function to that watches the set of cells for any changes (keyups) and runs the function passed to it again whenever any of that set of cells are changed.

```
function watchSet(set, mathFunction) {
    var setSize = set.length;
    for (var i=0; i < setSize; i++) {
        set[i].down().observe("keyup", function(){
            mathFunction
        });
    }
}
```

An example function that uses this is the qualtricsSum function (which also uses the mathSum function)

```
function mathSum(set, output) {
    var setTotal = 0;
    for (var j=0; j < (set.length); j++) {
        var setInputValue = parseInt(set[j].down().value, 10);
        if (isNaN(setInputValue)) { setInputValue = 0; }
        setTotal = setTotal + setInputValue;
    }
    output.down().value = setTotal;
}

function qualtricsSum(array, output) {
    watchSet(array, mathSum(array, output));
}
```

In the watchSet function I wrap the mathFunction I pass with `function(){...}` and it runs the mathSum function, but doesn't seem to run it on keyups, but if I don't wrap it with the unnamed function, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined` as an error. I'm not sure if that's part of my problem.

When I manually run the for loop that's in watchSet and replace mathFunction with the function I intend to run, it does actually run the function I give it every time I edit the cells. This makes me think that somehow calling watchSet(set, mathFunction) and then referencing mathFunction in the function definition doesn't actually pass what I'm thinking it is passing.

EDIT:
I realized once I saw behtgod's answer that I didn't clarify this:
I do not always know what mathFunction's arguments look like, and I would like to be able to pass any function with any number of arguments as the mathFunction. Sometimes it will be functions with a format like mathSum(array, output), other times I'd like it to be mathEqual(array), or any number of different kinds of things.

Comment: I've edited my question, but I should have clarified that I do not always know what the arguments of mathFunction will look like. I now have something working better where `qualtricsSum` calls `watchSet(array, function(){mathSum(array,output)})`. However, it still gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined` frequently.

Answer (score 0):

First,your mathFunction is a function, so you should use it like

```
mathFunction();
```

Second,when below line is executed

```
watchSet(array, mathSum(array, output));
```

the mathSum have been called and only the result is pass to watchSet function.

So you should use like this:

```
function watchSet(set, mathFunction) {
    var setSize = set.length;
    for (var i=0; i < setSize; i++) {
        set[i].down().observe("keyup", function(set,output){
            mathFunction(set,output)
        });
    }
}

function mathSum(set, output) {
    ...
}


function qualtricsSum(array, output) {
    watchSet(array, mathSum);
}
```

because you mathFunction is called in a callback ,so the arguments which the mathFunction used,must be arguments of the callback

Comment: Ah, I should have clarified (and will edit my original post) -- I do not always know what the arguments of mathFunction (if any) will be. I may be misunderstanding, but in the way you've written it, doesn't this force that I pass set and output to mathFunction? I'm looking to build this such that I can pass different kinds of functions as the mathFunction with different kinds of arguments, not necessarily in the format mathFunction(set, output)  always.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, the mathFunction is also not passed to the callback of the keyup. You should get the function from outer scope rather than pass a argument to callback.